# Changing the login/register of joomla for PHP coding

Tags: php, joomla

I have more of a question than a problem.
At the moment I use Joomla for most of my websites because it is easy to use and maintain. But i have a website coming up that will require quite a lot of php code.
Implementing php code in Joomla is easy with sorcerer plugin, but the login module is going to be the problem.

Here is the problem in short:
I need to use tools like a layer slider, popups etc, all of which i can simply buy and use with Joomla.
But the user login is very limited. I need the login module to link to a completely different table, where i can manage all the fields.

There are going to be quite a number of fields in addition to the basic username/password combo, and each of these fields must be easily accessible in a profile page(which I can make in php, but if it is in a table like the one present, it may be a problem).

Is there any way to use Joomla to design the website, but basically scrap the entire login/register module Joomla uses and force a login state? or something of the like?

I want to keep Joomla's ease of designing the graphics while incorporate the php power. (Most of the website will be limited to logged in users)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin with name "User - Profile" , enable it , and select the fields that you want be in registration form and profile page

if you didn't find your needed fields and need to do some hard coding to add them, do with this plugin ;)